# Issues updating rows in google sheets using gspread with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm creating a program for a game where it queries the games API, grabs data from there, I parse it internally into lists, then gspread would upload it to Google sheets in a document template I've created.
The lists are of multiple datatypes, and an example is listed below:

```
['Example', 7, 1, 9, 16, 247, 0.6153846153846154, 1726.6914683999998, 32517, 0.3731858415138197, 13896, 0.11760574089286983, 9441, 13101, 0.24403464654931545, 'Red', 2, 83, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 107, 176, 6231, 3088, 0, 31, 73, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

For the gspread api call, I'm using the following:

```
a_notation = "B" +str(row) + ":AT"+ str(row)
    
wks.update(a_notation, my_data_row3)
```

The row and start in the B column is to fit the document template I'm using.

I've been trying a variety of different ways to structure the data to make this work, however I've been getting rejected by the API consistently. Most recently, the common API response code is:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Requested writing within range [sotest!B3:AT3], but tried writing to row [4]', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

The worksheet name for this attempt was "sotest", so it does not have any weird characters or anything.

I've tried creating a list of lists, with each element being a "cell", but that too came back with its own errors. This is only a snippet, but it continues on for each cell. Example error message:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Example"\nInvalid value at \'data.values[1]\'
```

How are you supposed to call the Google Sheets API to update a range of cells within a single row using a list of different data types? ChatGPT has not been too helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation's "Updating cells" section](https://github.com/burnash/gspread#updating-cells), you need to wrap your whole dataset into another list. So instead of:

```
['Example', 7, 1, 9, ...]
```

you need to have:

```
[['Example', 7, 1, 9, ...]]
```

The nested list is required even if you're updating a single row but you can also wrap the dataset at runtime `my_data_row3 = [my_data_row3]` etc.